# Big header and page margins

Tags: header-footer, margins

I am trying to insert a big header, but it pushes the text and footer.

With short header I get this:

[image: Good]

But when I increase header size the text and footer move.

[image: Bad]
MWE:

```
\documentclass[headheight=24pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{
\vspace{.5cm}
Header
\vspace{.5cm}
}
\cfoot{
Footer
}
\begin{document}
First page text\footnote{first page footnote}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your MWE you should get two warning messages:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [headheight=24pt].

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 40.45273pt.
```

To resolve the first, remove the `[headheight=24pt]` option. It is not used and 24pt would nevertheless still be too small, as the second warnungs tells us. To remove the second warning, add `\setlength{\headheight}{40.5pt}` to your preamble.

[image]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{40.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{
\vspace{.5cm}
Header
\vspace{.5cm}
}
\cfoot{
Footer
}
\begin{document}
First page text\footnote{first page footnote}
\newpage
\end{document}
```